# WordPress database error: [Query was empty]

Tags: wordpress

I'm using $wpdb to connect to a different database than my wordpress one like this:

```
$newdb = new wpdb(DB_NEW_USER, DB_NEW_PASSWORD, DB_NEW_NAME, DB_NEW_HOST);
```

I need to insert multiple rows into the database. 
I used the code from this answer: [Wordpress $wpdb. Insert Multiple Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373903/wordpress-wpdb-insert-multiple-records).

To run the query, I use this line:

```
$newdb->query( $newdb->prepare("$query", $values));
```

When I do `echo $query`, this is the result: (there are more than 3 columns, but I shortened if for times sake)

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')
```

When I `var_dump($values)`, it returns an array with the same amout of strings as I have columns.

When I run the query, I get the following error:

```
WordPress database error: [Query was empty]
```

I tried selecting from the database in a similar fashion and it did work, so my connected to the db is working.

What am I doing wrong?

If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your query look like this?

```
$metakey = "Harriet's Adages";
$metavalue = "WordPress' database interface is like Sunday Morning: Easy.";

$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        array(
        10, 
        $metakey, 
        $metavalue
    ) 
) );
```

Comment: NO. It doesn't look same. Can you post your print_r of $values and echo of $query here?

Comment: thanks for your efforts, but I realized I had an extra value in my placeholders. when I took it out, it worked